# Default groups for user in Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: permissions

I accidentally removed my user from some groups yesterday because of some virtualbox issues and today I couldn't use sudo to do anything and had to use a livecd to edit sudoers.

Anyway I want to edit the user to be in the same groups it would be in the default installation but I don't which groups to add the user to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default groups for user in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219083/default-groups-for-user-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from your user's group, you are in

```
adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare
```

/etc/sudoers should look like this:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm a member of and I haven't changed anything since install:

```
wojox@wojox-desktop:~$ groups
wojox adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare
```

Just change wojox for your user name.