# Default groups for user in Ubuntu?

Tags: users

Installed [HP Linux Imaging and Printing](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html) by using install script and something crashed. Now I'm only member of my own group and `lp`.

Which are the default groups for users in for example Ubuntu 12.10? [Same as this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44520/default-groups-for-user-in-ubuntu-11-04)?

Out of curiosity, is there some place where this information is logged? For example, some log file showing which groups my user was on previous boot? Is this information, (which groups are default), documented somewhere?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

## A) Short answer

Default groups; say for user123, on fresh install - (use command `groups` in a terminal):

```
user123 adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

Gives diff from 11.04 as

- `admin` [is replaced by](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/TechnicalOverview/Alpha1#General) `sudo`
- `dialout` is removed
- `dip` is added.

To get/view defaults. Would probably work for various others too; do:

```
sudo grep user-setup /var/log/installer/syslog
```

---

---

## B) Restoring default groups

*(Adding this to make it more complete)*

### 1. Identifying the groups

I always set root password, but if you haven't use a live CD, live USB, other install etc. to get to the file.

If you **have** set root password (by i.e.):

```
sudo passwd root
```

and have lost `sudo` privileges do:

```
su - root
grep user-setup /var/log/installer/syslog
```

Gives you i.e.

```
... user-setup: pwconv: failed to change the mode of /etc/passwd- to 0600
... user-setup: Shadow passwords are now on.
... user-setup: Adding user `user123' ...
... user-setup: Adding new group `user123' (1000) ...
... user-setup: Adding new user `user123' (1000) with group `user123' ...
... user-setup: Creating home directory `/home/user123' ...
... user-setup: Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
... user-setup: addgroup: The group `lpadmin' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
... user-setup: Adding group `sambashare' (GID 124) ...
... user-setup: Done.
... user-setup: Adding user `user123' to group `adm' ...
... user-setup: Adding user user123 to group adm
... user-setup: Done.
... user-setup: Adding user `user123' to group `cdrom' ...
... user-setup: Adding user user123 to group cdrom
... user-setup: Done.
... user-setup: Adding user `user123' to group `dip' ...
... user-setup: Adding user user123 to group dip
... user-setup: Done.
... user-setup: Adding user `user123' to group `lpadmin' ...
... user-setup: Adding user user123 to group lpadmin
... user-setup: Done.
... user-setup: Adding user `user123' to group `plugdev' ...
... user-setup: Adding user user123 to group plugdev
... user-setup: Done.
... user-setup: Adding user `user123' to group `sambashare' ...
... user-setup: Adding user user123 to group sambashare
... user-setup: Done.
... user-setup: adduser: The group `debian-tor' does not exist.
... user-setup: Adding user `user123' to group `sudo' ...
... user-setup: Adding user user123 to group sudo
... user-setup: Done.
... ubiquity: Removing user-setup ...
... ubiquity: Purging configuration files for user-setup ...
```

Or:

```
su - root
grep "user-setup: Adding user user123 to group" /var/log/installer/syslog | cut -d' ' -f11
```

Which yields:

```
adm
cdrom
dip
lpadmin
plugdev
sambashare
sudo
```

(No idea why `dip` suddenly has become a default group by install. Something to do with `dialout` being removed?)

---

### 2.a Updating groups - using "built-in" root access

So do, as *root*, to add groups to user, i.e. user `user123`:

```
usermod -a -G adm,cdrom,lpadmin,sudo,sambashare,dip,plugdev user123
```

Where ([Somewhat outdated on 12.10](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Privileges)):

```
adm         Monitor system logs
cdrom       Use CD-ROM drives
lpadmin     Configure printers
sudo        administer the system, ...
sambashare  Share files with the local network
dip         Connect to the Internet using a modem
plugdev     Access external storage devices
```

Some extras you might need: (check what you have by `root@YOURPC:~# id -nG user123`)

```
dialout     ttyS*/Serial/COM1,COM2 ...
vboxusers   Virtual Box
user123     Your own group
```

If you want; double-check /etc/group , i.e. (here with some extras):

```
root@YOURPC:~# grep user123 /etc/group

adm:x:4:user123
audio:x:29:user123,timidity,pulse
video:x:44:user123
lp:x:7:user123
dialout:x:20:user123
cdrom:x:24:user123
sudo:x:27:user123
dip:x:30:user123
plugdev:x:46:user123
lpadmin:x:107:user123
user123:x:1000:
sambashare:x:124:user123
vboxusers:x:127:user123
autologin:x:1001:user123
```

---

As an alternative one can boot in to rescue mode and

```
mount -o remount,rw /
usermod -G adm,cdrom,lpadmin,sudo,sambashare,dip,plugdev user123
```

---

**Log out and log in**. Groups should be updated.

---

### 2.b Updating groups - using root access from Live-CD etc.

`xxx` here is where your file-system is mounted when running a live edition, i.e. `/media/foo`.

Manually edit the file `/xxx/etc/group` using [vigr](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vigr) and add user as in previous listing.

Or; only add user to sudo; as in:

```
sudo:x:27:user123
```

Boot into your installation and update by executing the `usermod` command with `sudo`:

```
sudo usermod -a -G adm,cdrom,lpadmin,sudo,sambashare,dip,plugdev user123
```

**Log out and log in**. Groups should be updated.

---

Double Note: `admin` is no longer part of Ubuntu as of 11.10 in favour of `sudo`.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very detailed, and very useful for people who have accidentally messed up their user's groups.

Comment: @rcourtna: Thanks. That's how I ended up here myself. Took some hacking before I found the `sudo cat /var/log/installer/syslog | grep user-setup` :)

Comment: NOTE: Command `usermod -G adm,cdrom,lpadmin,sudo,sambashare,dip,plugdev ` (section 2.a) contains error: `usermod` require user to be specified. Command should look: `usermod -G adm,cdrom,lpadmin,sudo,sambashare,dip,plugdev user123` _(I've fixed that via edit, but my change was rejected for some reason.)_

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the own user group, the user of a fresh installation is in the following default groups:

| Ubuntu Version | Default Groups |
| --- | --- |
| Ubuntu 11.04 | adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare |
| Ubuntu 12.10 | adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare |
| Ubuntu 14.04 LTS | adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare |
| Ubuntu 15.10 | adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare |
| Ubuntu 18.04 LTS | adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare |
| Ubuntu 20.04 LTS | adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare |