# user created unable to login

Tags: command-line, users, useradd

I created a user in terminal by

```
useradd xyz
```

I'm able to log in from the terminal but not in the GUI.

What is wrong?

Comment: How do you log in from the terminal? Have you created user's password?

Comment: @Melebius this is not a duplicate of the question you linked in my opinion since the OP doesn't know that no home directory was created and didn't use the `-d` option but rather no options at all.

Comment: @derHugo AFAIK it does not work that way. A duplicate question means that the answers to another question can be applied to it, so the community can maintain just one list of answers for such a situation.

Answer (score 6):

This might be because `useradd` didn't create a home directory for your new user. You should use

```
adduser xyz
```

instead and avoid using `useradd` since it is a backend command needing more input.

See also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/374878/423684), [man useradd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd) and [man adduser](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/adduser.8.html).

---

Or 
if you still want to use `useradd` use at least

```
useradd -m xyz
```

to create a home directory. **But this still might be insufficient.**

---

Before starting now you might want to remove the user you created wrong by

```
userdel xyz
```

so you can create it again correctly without problems.

---

**Anyway**:
If you have a GUI it might be easier to just use the GUI for adding the new user (usually somewhere in System-settings -> Accounts). This might also solve some problems with usergroups which might appear as @Videonauth pointed out.

Comment: you should add that this new user should be added to some groups too, like `usermod -aG adm,cdrom,sudo,dip,plugdev,lpadmin,sambashare <username>`. Leave suo out if you not want this user to have sudo rights and in case of sambashare not a group leave this out as well.

Comment: Or do it all in one command `useradd -U -m -G adm,cdrom,dip,plugdev,lpadmin <username>`

Comment: Thanks @Videonauth I never needed those groups but well .. I'm not using GUIs ^^ And when I do I always added those users within the GUI so I don't now which groups really are necessary to be added manually. `adduser` actually should already do a lot of that automatically..

Comment: When in terminal with your main user, type `groups` to see in which groups he is in. :) For me it returns the above mentioned ones on 17.10 and it was no different on 16.04 and all in between.

Comment: Regarding user groups see [this useful answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/219353/522934).

Comment: @Videonauth thanks for your afforts but I may repeat: `adduser` (which is and works different from `useradd`) should do that automatically using the systems `/etc/adduser.conf` ([man /etc/adduser.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/adduser.conf.5.html) -> `EXTRA_GROUPS
              This is the list of groups that new  non-system  users  will  be
              added  to.  By default, this list is 'dialout cdrom floppy audio
              video plugdev users games'`). Basic usergoups should be added by default unless you changed it in this configuration.