# Usermod and history output

Tags: 16.04, permissions, sudo, history

I used `usermod -G` without the `-a` option, now the main user has only 2 groups. I want to restore all the previous groups but the problem is that i need to list all the groups before the changes

I am trying to use

> locate /etc/groups

and grep username in the previous version of the file to get all the previous group

How can I access to the file from the db and read them ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default groups for user in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219083/default-groups-for-user-in-ubuntu)

Comment: And you'll probably need https://askubuntu.com/q/70442/158442 as well to get back your lost sudo rights.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `/etc/groups`. There's `/etc/group` and `/etc/group-` (the backup). To get results for your user from the backup, you can do:

```
grep username /etc/group-
```

Or, to get just the groups, using awk:

```
awk -F: -v u=username '$NF ~ u {print $1}' /etc/group-
```

To then add those groups back, as root:

```
awk -F: -v u=username '$NF ~ u {print $1}' /etc/group- |
  xargs -n1 gpasswd -a username
```